# rounding image borders with css is not working when nested

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

EDIT: This must be some other issue with django and how it refreshes the CSS.  I have made several changes to the css it now and see no changes when I reload the page.

It does have some .scss files along with it, I have changed those too and still see no changes.  I am doing a `{% load staticfiles %}` which maybe isn't pulling the right files? I mean it is the site works, but its not picking up changes some how.

Closing this though, as it all works as intended in firefox, just not chrome?

I wanted to round the edges of an image within a specific div.  Thought this is how I did it:

```css
/* 13.0 Service CSS */
.single-service-area {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center; }
  .single-service-area img {
border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .single-service-area .service-icon {
background-color: #e7f2fd;
width: 145px;
height: 110px;
font-size: 42px;
color: #303030;
text-align: center;
line-height: 110px;
border-radius: 80px 200px 200px 362px;
margin: 0 auto 30px;
-webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
-o-transition-duration: 500ms;
transition-duration: 500ms; }
  .single-service-area h5 {
font-size: 22px;
display: block;
margin-bottom: 15px;
-webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
-o-transition-duration: 300ms;
transition-duration: 300ms;
font-weight: 600; }
  .single-service-area:focus .service-icon, .single-service-area:hover .service-icon {
background-color: #1583e9;
color: #ffffff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 50px 8px rgba(21, 131, 233, 0.15);
box-shadow: 0 6px 50px 8px rgba(21, 131, 233, 0.15); }
  .single-service-area:focus h5, .single-service-area:hover h5 {
color: #1583e9; }
```

```html
   <section class="uza-services-area section-padding-80-0">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Section Heading -->
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="section-heading text-center">
                        <h2>Our Telescopes</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <!-- Single Service Area -->
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
                 <div class="single-service-area mb-80">
                  <img src="{% static '/img/bg-img/7.jpg' %}" alt="" ></img>                       
                  <h5>Business Strategy</h5>
                  <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet gubergren no sea takimata.</p>
                </div>
               </div>
       
<!-- Single Service Area -->
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="single-service-area mb-80">
                        <!-- Service Icon -->
                        <div class="service-icon">
                            <i class="icon_piechart"></i>
                        </div>
                        <h5>Market Analytics</h5>
                        <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet gubergren no sea takimata.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Single Service Area -->
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="single-service-area mb-80">
                        <!-- Service Icon -->
                        <div class="service-icon">
                            <i class="icon_easel"></i>
                        </div>
                        <h5>Marketing Social</h5>
                        <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet gubergren no sea takimata.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

But it does not work, if I move the img css portion outside of the class.  It works fine....(but of course for all images in div or not)

Comment: there is a spelling mistake in your class name ".single-service-aera img {". It should work once you fix that.

Comment: Check your css, it says "single-service-aera" instead of "single-service-area". Most likely that's the issue.

Comment: fixed the typo on actual deployed django code, edited the CSS to add the img line to `single-service-area` didnt know if that it doesn't work in the html cause it is within so many other divs?

Comment: So, has the problem gone away now that you've corrected the typo?

Comment: no, the problem persists (original code didn't have typo).  I am trying to hack a template I found to have rounded corners for a section with images.  The small sample on jsfiddle did work after the typo was fixed, but the larger code base still does not work.  I added the full html code from the sections and the relevant CSS all from larger code base

Comment: Someone has to ask the silly questions, did you clear your cache when you corrected the typo? Try loading in incognito, just to be sure....

Comment: cleared the cache, something wonky on it , I had to clear it twice and then finally it took.  Oh hells bells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img class="test" src="{% static '/img/bg-img/7.jpg' %}" alt="" ></img>   


.test{
border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

try like that. See if it works.